# Error Message after just changing my SolrUrl to my local Solr server: resource was blocked due to MIME type mismatch

Tags: javascript, solr

I just started using AJAX Solr to implement a demo from scratch.
(https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki/Reuters-tutorial%3A-step-1)

I built my local Solr data from reuter data downloaded from the tutorial link. I used Solr 9.4.0 to set up my local collection, reuterdata, and tested it in the Solr Admin.

The query worked fine in Solr Admin UI but after I started modifying my reuters.js file and changed solrUrl to my local Solr URL which is "http://localhost:8983/solr/reuterdata/", it came across an error immediately.  I only made this small change, and I did not touch any other codes. When I loaded the index.html from my local folder, I expected the reuter data from my local Solr can be loaded into the HTML page, but it didn't show up. It only showed some h2  texts no contents under these h2 texts. I used firebug to debug the error. There was the following error:

"The resource from “http://localhost:8983/solr/reuterdata/select?facet=true&q=*%3A*&facet.field=topics&facet.field=organisations&facet.field=exchanges&facet.field=countryCodes&facet.limit=20&facet.mincount=1&f.topics.facet.limit=50&f.countryCodes.facet.limit=-1&facet.date=date&facet.date.start=1987-02-26T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%2FDAY&facet.date.end=1987-10-20T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%2FDAY%2B1DAY&facet.date.gap=%2B1DAY&json.nl=map&wt=json&json.wrf=jQuery172003692584046418779_1706919458200&_=1706919458231” was blocked due to MIME type (“application/json”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."

"Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost:8983/solr/reuterdata/select?facet=true&q=*%3A*&facet.field=topics&facet.field=organisations&facet.field=exchanges&facet.field=countryCodes&facet.limit=20&facet.mincount=1&f.topics.facet.limit=50&f.countryCodes.facet.limit=-1&facet.date=date&facet.date.start=1987-02-26T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%2FDAY&facet.date.end=1987-10-20T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%2FDAY%2B1DAY&facet.date.gap=%2B1DAY&json.nl=map&wt=json&json.wrf=jQuery172003692584046418779_1706919458200&_=1706919458231”.

My questions:

1. Why was the resource from Solr blocked? Is that due to this new Solr version as I knew this AJAX-Solr was built many years ago and may not be compatible with new Solr version.
2. Why can the scripts be loaded even though I didn't change anything except the SolrUrl address?

Any replies will be appreciated. Thank you so much.